# Why Visual Studio code not finding my Azure subscriptions

Tags: reactjs, node.js, azure, azure-functions, azure-web-app-service

See this image i have successfully login to Azure in Visual Studio Code and select tenant id after that i am trying to select subscription but there is no subscription available]

[image]

Comment: Are you able to see your [Account](https://i.imgur.com/7OS19L8.png) in Accounts section.

Comment: You must install [Azure Resources](https://i.imgur.com/US628jq.png) Extension to view the resources.

Comment: Is your Azure Subscription Active ?Login to the portal and check whether you are able to access the resources.

Answer (score 0):

Initially I have signed into the Azure Account which is not active and can see the option to select Directory.

[image]

- I also tried to login to the account which does not have any Azure Subscription. Then I can see the option to `Select Subscriptions` same as your screenshot.

[image]

- Finally, signed in with my active azure subscription, I can see the Azure Resources (Subscriptions).

[image]

- You must have an active Azure subscription to see the Resources.
- To make sure you have signed into the correct account, Login to the Azure portal with the same account and check whether you are able to see the Resources.

Comment: Yes it works exactly i had this problem now it works ,Thank you

Comment: Glad.. the issue is resolved..